# Ubuntu 14.04 GCC 4.8.2 link dynamically against (older) GLIBC 2.11.1

Tags: 14.04, gcc, g++, glibc

For the needs of my project I need to use G++ 4.8.2 and GLIBC 2.11.1.

Ubuntu 14.04 comes with EGLIBC 2.19. **How can I make G++ link dynamically against GLIBC 2.11.1?**

If there is, **how do I go about getting GLIBC 2.11.1**? Can I download it from Ubuntu's repository? Should I build it from source? Or should I install Ubuntu 10.04 (which contains my desired GLIBC version) and copy it to my Ubuntu 14.04?

If there isn't I guess I'll just have to use Ubuntu 10.04 and update G++ to 4.8.2. In that case, **when I update from 4.4.3 (the default version in Ubuntu 10.04) to 4.8.2, will that update GLIBC too?**

Please be as verbose as possible, and possibly give me some instructions.

Thanks in advance to anyone who replies!

**Solution:**

I tried using libc.so and ld-linux.so from Ubuntu 10.04 in Ubuntu 14.04, it linked to my version of ld-linux.so, but it kept using it's own version of libc.so. I decided to just use Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Never mark the title as [SOLVED], AND post the solution as an answer, don't merge that in body of your question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can download any version of GLIBC here:

http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/

Then just link like any other I would think..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions:
- Cross-compiling GCC against the older libraries
- You can set the rpath to pick-up your preferred libraries first.
...

Since this is a very old question I won't go into much detail.